# Slicing a date range that includes time

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe which contains a column `Date` & `Time`, with each row containing an entry in the format:  `MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS`

I would like to be able to slice the dataframe based on only a date range, say for instance:  `5/01/2016 to 5/30/2016`.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: dataframe where? in an sql table? you should redo your dates to be a db-native date/datetime value, and then your question becomes a trivial `where datefield between '2016-05-01' and '2016-05-30'`

Comment: If they're both `datetime` objects; you can simple subtract them and get a `timedelta` object?

Comment: Unfortunately I have no control over the date/time format.  It's an input to a CSV file from another application I do not control, so I need to be able to report based on a date range; the time is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) to select the subset of the dataframe for which the condition (*interval between dates*) is satisfied:

**Data Preparation**

```
In [13]: from io import StringIO
    ...: import pandas as pd
    ...: 

In [14]: df = pd.read_csv(StringIO('''
    ...: Date
    ...: 5/01/2016 00:00:00
    ...: 5/02/2016 00:00:00
    ...: 5/03/2016 00:00:00
    ...: 5/04/2016 00:00:00
    ...: 5/05/2016 00:00:00
    ...: 5/06/2016 00:00:00
    ...: 5/07/2016 00:00:00
    ...: 5/08/2016 00:00:00
    ...: 5/09/2016 00:00:00
    ...: 5/010/2016 00:00:00
    ...: '''))
```

**Operations**

```
In [15]: df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

In [16]: start = "5/02/2016"
    ...: end = "5/05/2016"

In [17]: mask = (df['Date'] >= pd.to_datetime(start)) & (df['Date'] <= pd.to_datetime(end))

In [18]: df.loc[mask]
Out[18]: 
        Date
1 2016-05-02
2 2016-05-03
3 2016-05-04
4 2016-05-05
```

Answer (score 0):

for variables sdate and edate

```
frame = []
record = 0
for date,time in my_list:
  if date == sdate or record == 1:
    frame.append([date,time])
    record = 1
  if date == edate:
    break;

print (frame)
```